# If current_path = http://

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to call the current path in a php condition and compare it with a defined path.

More specifically, in my website, users don't have permissions to do certain actions, but I want them to have these permissions if they are in the repertory that has been created for them when they registered.

I can get my user's username with

```
$_SESSION['simple_auth']['username']
```

and what i'm trying to do is something with the following shape :

> if current_path == 'http:/mywebsite/user-section/name_of_the_user' {

After some researchs I found that the function get_cwd() might be the one I'm looking for, but I'm a but struggling to write it properly, being very new in php.

I'm looking for some help and explanations on how to realize this !

Thanks a lot !

- Apatik

Comment: Can you show us a little more of your code or the path you're using ?

Comment: Check the command phpinfo (http://php.net/manual/de/function.phpinfo.php) and have a look on all the variables set. You may found what looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you're looking for information from `$_SERVER`, probably `REQUEST_URI`.

> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = The URI which was given in order to access this page; for instance, '/index.html'.

You should look at everything that you can get in the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

You also might find the following for working out both what is available and what you want:

```
var_dump($_SERVER)
```

with a nod to @Nirnae.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! however I'm not too sure this what i'm looking for, what i need is more the path than the current page, i want to have my user get their permissions when they are in a specific repertory, for instance if user_1 is in hhtp:/website.com/user/user_1/ then he is granted his permissions. Thanks again

Comment: @apatik this is the answer you're looking for. You can use substring for this to get the page you want.

Comment: Since i have the feeling i'm not providing enough info, here is the exact path my where i want my users to have permissions : http:/website.home/ftp/?cd=user/user_1 (it's actually the path where i want my user to be able to freely upload files)

Comment: Yep, and if you go and look at all the components, you will see things like `'SCRIPT_FILENAME' and `PATH_INFO`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the full path of the current file with the filename included, `__FILE__` can be used:

```
<?php
  print __FILE__;
?>
```

Result:

```
/home/mamba/programming/so/php/test.php
```

If pieces of the path are needed, `__FILE__` can be combined with pathinfo:

```
<?php
      print_r( pathinfo( __FILE__ ) );
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [dirname] => /home/mamba/programming/so/php
    [basename] => test.php
    [extension] => php
    [filename] => test
)
```